# ActionBar Sherlock - Backgroundimage in Actionbar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I would love to set a Backgroundimage to the ActionBar which I imported with the "ActionBar Sherlock" library. However I can't find any link on the internet on how to distinctively set an BackgroundImage with XML.

Does anybody here have a hint which he could give me :)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create a style for your actionbar, it has to inherit *Theme.Sherlock* or *Theme.Sherlock.Light*.

Then link to your image in the attribute *abBackground*.

Assuming you have an image called myBackgroundImage in *res/drawable* your style xml would be:

```
<style name="Actionbar" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="abBackground">@drawable/myBackgroundImage</item>
</style>
```

You can find more attributes for the actionbar here: [ActionBarSherlock - Theming](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html)

More on styles is found here: [Styles and Themes | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme)

Answer (score 2):

In your style.xml file add a custom style like this:

```
<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_bg</item>

    </style>
```

and add this style to your app theme with this to lines, the first for the Android <3.0 and the second for the >3.0

```
<style name="ReservasAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
        </style>
```

You should add this style to the application tag in manifest

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look at : http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html